# match files based on an md5 using find

Tags: find, regular-expression

I have a bunch js and css files in a directory. Some of them have been given a name based on an md5() of their content (looks like `f10521a21bb013cb81e0909809818ad6.js`). I'd like to match these files using find. Why does this return 0 results?

```
find -regex "^[A-f0-9]{32}\.(?:js|css)$"
```

Comment: Instead of A-f, I guess you either mean a-f, or A-Fa-f.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The regular expression is matched against the path, not just the file name, so do not anchor it to the beginning of string.
- The default emacs type regular expression seems to not like intervals. Choose another.
- Neither the other regular expression types seem to like the non capturing groups.

These work, supposing you are using GNU `find`:

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*/[a-f0-9]{32}\.(js|css)$"

find . -regextype posix-basic -regex ".*/[a-f0-9]\{32\}\.\(js\|css\)$"

find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/[a-f0-9]{32}\.(js|css)$"

find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "/[a-f0-9]{32}\.(js|css)$"
```